# Kendo UI Splitter resize

Tags: resize, kendo-ui, splitter

I have a Tabstrip, where one of the Tabs contains a Splitter. The problem is that the Splitter doesn't appear normally when I click the tab - the left pane has zero size, and the right pane is blank. If I expand the left pane, it shows normally.

I found this problem here too: [Kendo UI Forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/splitter/splitter-within-tab-not-sizing-properly.aspx)

So I used the code provided:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
animation: false,
select: function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(e.contentElement).find(".k-splitter").each(function() {
            $(this).data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
        });
    });
}
});
```

And for some past kendo release it worked even with `animation:true`!

However, after I started to use the Q3 beta, and now the full Q3, the above code ONLY works if I put an `alert("")` before the trigger command! With the alert it works fine, without it I get the old messed up results again.

My current code is:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation : {
        open : {
            duration : 200,
            effects : "fadeIn"
        }
    },
    select : function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(e.contentElement).find(".k-splitter").each(function() {
                $(this).show(500, function() {
                    alert("");
                    $(this).data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
                });
            });
        });
    }
});

$("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
    panes : [
        {
            collapsible : true,
            size : "17%",
            scrollable: false
        },
        {
            collapsible : false,
            resizable: false,
            scrollable: false
        },
        {
            collapsible : true,
            size : "20%",
            scrollable: false
        },
    ],
});
```

Am I forgetting something? The whole thing with the `alert("")` doesn't really makes sense, and of course I don't want an alert every time I select the tab.

PS: If I put `animation:false`, then the code works without the `alert("")`, but I want to keep the animation as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the **setTimeout** function a duration (second parameter) longer than that of your animation.

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation : {
        open : {
            duration : 200,
            effects : "fadeIn"
        }
    },
    select: function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(e.contentElement).find(".k-splitter").each(function() {
                $(this).data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
            });
        }, 300);
    }          
});
```

Here is example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FLLJv/53/

Comment: Using `setTimeout` to create a delay is usually a bad solution. In the worst case scenario it will create a race condition on slower machines or for some other reason and in the best case you lose a 100ms for nothing after the animation is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `activate` event for the TabStrip:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
  activate: function(e) {
    $(e.contentElement).find('.k-splitter').trigger('resize');
  }
});
```

It's possible there are drawbacks where animation is concerned, but it seems less messy than mucking with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `resize` code in the [activate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-activate) event handler, not the `select` event handler, which fires after the animation has endede as well. Then you can remove the `setTimeout` altogether:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation : {
        open : {
            duration : 200,
            effects : "fadeIn"
        }
    },
    activate: function(e) {
        $(e.contentElement).find(".k-splitter").each(function() {
            $(this).data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
        });
    }          
});
```